# Is `function(x) = (=expression)` a valide expression

Tags: notation

So, I have a basic mathematical knowledge but I have been dealing with complex data structures and formulas part of my computer science skills.

Today morning, in the "Paris Nord" one of biggest Paris subways stations, this formula caught my attention (in the link). My intuition says, = must be left handed and right handed by another expression; which is not the case.

Mathisfun.com says

> Parentheses or "round brackets" are the familiar ( ) symbols used in
>   pairs to group things together.

and my data structure knowledge says:
Parenthesis can be used to specify a not scalar type, like tuples; In the same way as brackets define a different structure.

knowing this, I can grasp the notion of defining a structure, on a value.
But I know this is not the case here; so What I am missing.

[image: Formula]

Comment: The expression/equation is indeed very weird. What does the $=$-symbol point at? Nothing!

Comment: This is probably off-topic here, but anyhow, what language is this?

Comment: @Matti, yes I was excited to post here among mathematicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it most likely means $$r(T,h)=\frac{0.622he_8(T)}{p-he_8(T)}$$ and $$r(T,h)<r_{min}$$

Comment: Where does the extra $0$ come from ? Just to continue the joke !

Comment: Form the source of TYPOs.

Comment: Now I got it, so it's valid.

Comment: What is valid? .

Comment: not sure, but I got the thing that f(x) (=expression) < value ; I mean I see we are avoiding this way: f(x) = expression  < value or (f(x) = expression)  < value

Comment: It's just convention. What we mean is more important? This is however very uncommon way to write this(and therefore bad convention). I won't suggest making dwelling too much on this.